# Change background images jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

trying to change background images using css() method... not sure what is the best method to do this. I tried to copy, the first instance I am using toggle to change the switch image, and its working fine, it also changes the background image to day...

```
$('.switch').on('click', function(){
    $('.night, .day').toggle();
    $('body').css('background','url(img/day.jpg)');
}),
```

in the second instance is that I am having a problem, I want to switch back to the original night.jpg, but is not working..

```
$('.switch').on('click', function(){
    $('body').css('background','url(img/night.jpg)');
})
```

Here is a somewhat working bin...
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kigelenawo/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 4):

I would toggle a `.night` class on `<body>` in this situation.

You can do like...

```
$('.switch').on('click', function () {
  $('body').toggleClass('night');
});
```

Then in your CSS have something like:

```
body {
  background-image: url('img/day.jpg');
}

body.night {
  background-image: url('img/night.jpg');
}
```

Unless the value for a CSS property is dynamic it's much easier to handle it directly in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Combine both click handlers. If you use 2 of them they will both be triggered

A simple way to keep track of state would be to toggle a class on the switch

```
$('.switch').on('click', function(){
    var isOn = $(this).hasClass('on');
    var img = isOn ?'img/day.jpg' : 'img/night.jpg';
    $('.night, .day').toggle(isOn);
    $('body').css('background','url('+img+')');
     $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

That being said the use of css for this would be far simpler and only requires toggling the class on body